# Mass renaming via regex - python workaround

Tags: python, regex, bash, recursion, rename

i want to rename all special chars in many files to underlines via bash.
since i found out that i wont be able to use bash i wanna use python to do this.
this is my bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/dave/files/ -depth -execdir rename '
s/ä/ae/g;
s/ö/oe/g;
s/ü/ue/g;
s/Ä/Ae/g;
s/Ö/Oe/g;
s/Ü/Ue/g;
s/ß/ss/g;
s/\x3C/_/g; # <
s/\x3E/_/g; # >
s/\x5C/_/g; # \
s/\x3A/_/g; # :
s/\x3F/_/g; # ?
s/\x2A/_/g; # *
s/\x7C/_/g; # |
s/\x22/_/g; # "
' -v "{}" \;
echo "Done"
```

unfortunately i have very little experience with python and i dont find many similar examples.
can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Create a dictionary with translations:

```
trans = {'ä': 'ae',
         'Ä': 'Ae', ... }
```

which can be accessed with `trans.get(char, char)`, which returns a translated character if translatable, the character itself otherwise.

Translate the filenames using this line:

```
new_name = ''.join(trans.get(char, char) for char in old_name)
```

And now take a list of all files you want to rename and apply

```
os.rename(old_name, new_name)
```